No floppy disk in Windows 10 disk manager
I have noticed there were no floppy disc in the disc management in Windows 10. Please tell me if it should be so. The floppies are inserted and recognized. If this should be, please inform me about showing diskettes in this tools in earlier versions of Windows.

If there's a working diskette drive Windows should recognize it, as anachronistic as it sounds.

I have a Windows 2000 upgrade DVD and Windows 98 upgrade DVD collecting dust. I installed Windows 2000 in a virtual machine and added a blank virtual 1.44 MB 3.5" floppy to the virtual floppy drive A:. The floppy does not show in Disk Management. Installed Service Pack 4. No change. See image below. For better view, click on image or open image in a new window.

This goes back 24 years. Should I go back further? If so, how far and which Windows version? (NT 4, Me, 95, 98, etc.).

thank you for your job and answer. Sorry for late response.

Disk management will not show floppy drives, not even if a floppy is inserted.
Floppy drives will show up in device manager, but not in Disk management, because technically it is not a disk drive, but a floppy drive.
USB drives emulate disk drives, and for that reason, they do show up in disk management, but floppy drives predates disk drives.

I'm...not sure I buy this explanation. Neither the terminology part (floppy what? it's a floppy disk drive, that's literally where the name comes from) nor technical.

@grawity_u1686 maybe my explanation of why is not necessarily correct, its just that I never have seen a floppy drive appear in disk management. Maybe the reason is that you cannot partition a floppy, I dunno...

Floppy disks do not have a partition table and therefore disk management would have nothing to manage with respect to partitioning.
